# PyMongo: How can I fetch documents from a collection based on a field from a document in another collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, lookup

I'm trying to fetch documents from a collection with an identifier field that matches a field in another collection. This is so users can only see surveys that they have created. My collections are structured like this (removed most fields);

users

```
name:     "John"    
surname:  "Doe"
groupId:  "01-11"
username: "jdoe"
_id:      objectId(xxx)
```

surveys

```
groupId:  "01-11"
Results:   []
...other fields
```

What I need to do is;

- Fetch the user document based on username
- Retrieved groupId from user document
- Fetch all surveys that match the groupId from the user document

The query I wrote for this is;

```
qry = [
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "user",
            "localField": "groupId",
            "foreignField": "groupId",
            "as": "user_data"
        }
    },

    {
        "$match": {
            "user_data.username": "jdoe"
        }
    },

    {
        "$project": {
            "user_data": 0
        }
    }
]
```

This is more of a work around than a solution as it joins the two documents, which I don't want. Also, the user_data needs to be removed from every result. I just need to retrieve the surveys without joining the matching user document. I understand that this can easily be achieved with two find calls, one to find the user, and another to find the documents but I would like to reduce the number of calls I make as much as I can.

Thanks for your help,

O.

edit:

My desired output is simply the document[s] from the survey. For example;

```
{'_id': ObjectId('xxx'), 'groupId': '01-11', 'Results': []}
```

Without the "$project" parameter in the query above, I get;

```
{'_id': ObjectId('xxx'), 'groupId': '01-11', 'results': [...stuff], 'user_data': [{'_id': ObjectId('yyy'), 'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Doe', 'username': '76774', 'username': 'jdoe', 'groupId': '01-11'}]}
```

Comment: could you add your prefer output  ?

Comment: Added them to the end of the question.

Comment: so let me know you want after lookup search all group that is same with group of user with username : jdoe?

Comment: I want to search all surveys with a groupId that is the same as jdoe's groupId

Comment: and you want do it in one query?

Comment: I would prefer one query, like I'm using right now, but without "joining" documents from user and survey

Comment: look at this I think your query is ok 
https://mongoplayground.net/p/jHufNdh8QXU

Comment: It works' but it's quite slow. I just need to reference the groupId from the document in the user collection and then get all surveys with a matching groupId field

Comment: when you use lookup and this relation is groupId you didn't need to match